# How to convert Slide from Left Curtain Menu , to Slide in From Right

Tags: javascript, html, css

### The Problem

We need a curtain to animate from right hand side of screen , inwards to the left.

I found an *almost* PERFECT example of this ( except this only comes in from the left, animates to the right ).

**Working Example** [ left to right ]
[https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_curtain_menu.asp][1](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_curtain_menu.asp)

[image]

Below is the working code ( again, except left to right ):

**HTML**

```
<!-- The overlay -->
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

  <!-- Button to close the overlay navigation -->
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <!-- Overlay content -->
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- Use any element to open/show the overlay navigation menu -->
<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
```

**CSS**

```
/* The Overlay (background) */
.overlay {
  /* Height & width depends on how you want to reveal the overlay (see JS below) */    
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Black fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9); /* Black w/opacity */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Disable horizontal scroll */
  transition: 0.5s; /* 0.5 second transition effect to slide in or slide down the overlay (height or width, depending on reveal) */
}

/* Position the content inside the overlay */
.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%; /* 25% from the top */
  width: 100%; /* 100% width */
  text-align: center; /* Centered text/links */
  margin-top: 30px; /* 30px top margin to avoid conflict with the close button on smaller screens */
}

/* The navigation links inside the overlay */
.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block; /* Display block instead of inline */
  transition: 0.3s; /* Transition effects on hover (color) */
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position the close button (top right corner) */
.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

/* When the height of the screen is less than 450 pixels, change the font-size of the links and position the close button again, so they don't overlap */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
/* Open when someone clicks on the span element */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

/* Close when someone clicks on the "x" symbol inside the overlay */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
```

### An Ideal Solution

Well, most importantly, I need the curtain to come from right hand side of screen.

Addiationally, it would be fantastic if the curtain width would only be 25% of the screen. It's going to be more of an informational panel, than a menu.

**My Efforts**

I am fairly new to the modern CSS world, but I tried playing with the left property:

```
left: 500;  /* I need to start from right hand side of screen */
```

as far as the width goes, I tried:

```
 width: 25%; /* I think this will work */
```

I assume somehow I need to get right hand coordinate, and start the animation there? Not sure, this is above my pay grade, lol.

Any help sure would be appreciated. Thank you very much for looking.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is instead of `left: 0` in `.overlay` turn it into `right: 0` to allow it to open from right hand side. Also, in the `JavaScript` part change the `width` to `25%` not `100%` and you're done !

Here's a demo (the old comments are removed to allow the new comments to be distinguishable) :

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "25%"; /** from 100% to 25% **/
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  right: 0;
  /** it was left: 0, now it opens from right **/
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  overflow-x: hidden;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 25%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 36px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover,
.overlay a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay a {
    font-size: 20px
  }
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myNav" class="overlay">

  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>

  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">About</a>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <a href="#">Clients</a>
    <a href="#">Contact</a>
  </div>

</div>

<span onclick="openNav()">open</span>
```

Comment: WOW , I can't believe , #1 How quickly you answered, and #2 How simple the solution appears to be!!

Thank you. Of course, seeing the changes you made now make perfect sense to me. LOL , I was off trying to get right hand offsets, parent positions, etc! Thank you so much.

Comment: can you tell me how you embed your code to run? How do I add a "run code snippet" button to my code? That is so handy!

Comment: @JohnS. In the editor where you write questions/answers, at the top menu there is a `button` with an image having symbol like `</>` or press `CTRL + M` when focus is on the editor's text area.