# How to attach an image onto another element in certain spot?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Not sure if I worded my question well enough... here goes,

I am trying to re-create the behavior as shown in the image below:

**Desired Result**
[image]

I know how to make the panel slide in from the right, as shown here (except they come in from left): https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_curtain_menu.asp

So my question is, how would I affix the "X" close button??

Thanks for looking...

Ps. Here is the link to the curtain sliding in from the right: [How to convert Slide from Left Curtain Menu , to Slide in From Right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57154928/how-to-convert-slide-from-left-curtain-menu-to-slide-in-from-right/57154997?noredirect=1#comment100825392_57154997)

Comment: Position absolute with negative left value to match it's width

Comment: I don't understand clearly your issue, could you add some explanations.

Comment: Ok, I need to know how to add that blue little box with the X on it. I have the panel animated, but don't know how to position the "X".

Answer (score 0):

Function call to hide naveBar.

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
 }
```

Calling from:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
```

Comment: If you change the width to 100% it will appear again. @chari explained the right way only.